# Smarty Foreach loop that add +1 to the classes it prints out

Tags: php, html, smarty

Im working whit smarty and im having trouble adding a +1 everytime it goes thruw the foreach loop instead it adds the same number to all of them. is there anyway to add a counter in smarty that add +1 for every class that he prints out so all the classes are different from each other.

```
 $title is defind as 0 in another file

 {foreach from=$articles item=article}
        <h2 class="title{$title + 1}">{$article[0]}</h2>
        <p class="article">{$article[1]}</p>
        <img class="image" src="{$article[2]}" alt="foobar" />
 {/foreach}
```

Comment: Take a look at `@index` or `@iteration` on the [Smarty foreach manual](https://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.foreach.tpl). No need for `$title`

Answer (score 0):

you can actually use a key / value pair

Use the key instead of a counter. This would be the right way.

```
{foreach from=$myArray key=k item=v}
     <li>{$k}: {$v}</li>
 {/foreach}
```

Here you can enable the key and this is a natural counter for Smarty. Now this key variable will move naturally with each loop giving you access to a counter. Which this one you can actually do math if you need it. In your code you are always adding 1, and that will not move.

More on this here https://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.foreach.tpl

Answer (score 0):

The answer above is good but if for some reasons you have to use your approach you need to redefine your variable `$title` during each iteration because now the value of it everytime is 0 before iteration. So it's gonna be something like

```
{foreach from=$articles item=article}
    {assign var='title' value=$title + 1}
    <h2 class="title{$title}">{$article[0]}</h2>
    <p class="article">{$article[1]}</p>
    <img class="image" src="{$article[2]}" alt="foobar" />
{/foreach}
```